# Probability of Millikan's drop gaining or losing charge during the experiment

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I performed Millikan's experiment with latex drops. I did not get the "step graph" that I wanted (though the precision of the experiment was really bad as seen in the figure). My first drop is actually a very good measurement ($2e$), but the graph doesn't show discrete values for the fundamental charge.

I would like to know how to compute the probability that some of my latex drops would pick up charge from ionized molecules in the air. Thanks a lot for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've talken your diagram and attempted to draw on the grid lines for $Q = 2e$, $Q=3e$, etc:

[image: Grid lines]

The problem is that the vertical spacing between the points is much smaller than $e$. If you were picking up ambient charge that charge would still have to increase in steps of $e$ and it isn't doing so.

I would guess that your experimental errors are larger than you think, and the errors are completely washing out the step changes in the charge.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you take the oil composition, maybe its octane, C4H8, look at its ionization energy which is 10.01 eV and calculate the probability of spontaneous emission using [Einstein coefficients](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/0470016043.app3/pdf). (Last formula in the document)